# Trello backend database security

Tags: trello, security

I'm trying to find out a bit more about the data security of Trello as I'm trying to introduce the use Trello at the company I work for.

The company is ISO 27001 accredited and is therefore hesitant to use any cloud based services. We have to put any new technology past our security review boards so can someone advise on the actual data security, i.e. is the database / backup aspects rather than the traffic which I know is SSL.

Comment: This might be better addressed by contacting Trello directly.

Comment: I've sent an email into their support desk, so will update this if I get a reply.

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://trello.com/privacy

We do not offer encryption on disk at this time. We are not seeking accreditation or auditing by any outside body at this point, so if that is a requirement for you, it's very likely you won't be able to use Trello for work.

Sorry.